# How to create 2 grids to scroll independently

Tags: gridview, datagrid, grid

How do I create 2 grids to scroll independently on the same page?

[see linke to description of the layout](http://www.coderunnerlabs.com/graphic-design-2/ui-coderunnerlabs-example/)

Comment: This works exactly as I was looking for. Great job!!! I'm not sure how to ask additional questions after I grant you the answer points, are there any additional css options to turn on, to provide, with fluid scrolling for the text? The text just stops after the button or scroll event is stopped by the user. Is there a continuation of the scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a CSS rule like the following to each of the grids:

```
.MyGrid
{
  position: relative:
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Add a CssClass attribute of `CssClass="MyGrid"` to the GridViews then.

Comment: any additional css options to turn on, to provide, with fluid scrolling for the text? The text just stops after the button or scroll event is stopped by the user. Is there a continuation of the scroll?

Comment: You might want to try [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/). But, with or without Transitions, you won't find a solution without applying JavaScript to it and you'll have to render/control the scroll bar manually.